# JSON string contains null value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this line of code:

```
Message m = new Message(ciphertext, cipherKey, DateTime.Now, currentUser, serverUser);
```

`currentUser` and `serverUser` have been initialized as follows

```
serverUser = new User("Server", "svr", "Server", serverPublicKey);
currentUser = new User("Charlie", "c", "Charlie", publicKey);
```

`m` is then Serialized

```
string jsonMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);
```

but the JSON string only shows the following

```
"{\"data\":\"ylPSml/wesmAqxP4DpZc7A==\",\"encryptedKey\":\"hlEX5u9eWeQb626ea4dq8D37jKyNkGGUMtdtrpKeaZxo5LfzRbCWvB9ZY5i3aL3RsG/XTf3vhLxPHztto/UJDVqGc+tQeGqUaVbgLJhCwmppmrEvciRrv3PRd/E8pCmmD69HVSN0/Vb0546AhPaI6OJqzhUpWRC+lcE7EEKNJT4=\",\"dateTime\":\"2016-01-07T19:18:08.315557+08:00\",\"dest\":null,\"src\":null}"
```

The fields for `dest` and `src` are both null. Am I doing this wrong or the `SerializeObject` function supposed to work this way?.

Edit

User and Message class:

```
public class User
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string publicKey { get; set; }

    public User(string displayName, string id, string name, string publicKey)
    {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }
}


public class Message
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public byte[] encryptedKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    public User dest { get; set; }
    public User src { get; set; }

    public Message(string data, byte[] encryptedKey, DateTime dateTime, User dest, User src)
    {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.data = data;
        this.encryptedKey = encryptedKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your *User* and *Message* class?

Comment: Ideally, post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong but you haven't given us enough information to say what.

Comment: Your `Message` constructor doesn't set `dest` or `src`. What should've been step 1 in debugging: if serialising `m` shows that `m.dest` is `null`, also check whether `m.dest` is `null` prior to the serialisation.

Comment: That was stupid of me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Message constructor is missing the initalisation of the the two User based properties and should look like the following:

```
public Message(string data, byte[] encryptedKey, DateTime dateTime, User dest, User src)
{
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.data = data;
    this.encryptedKey = encryptedKey;

    // Note these two lines:
    this.dest = dest;
    this.src = src;
}
```